# DRY combine two functions in one

Tags: javascript, dry

I am trying to refactor my code and have noticed I am repeating myself. Was wondering if there is a way to combine these two functions in one?

```
export const fn1 = article => article.categoryValueDtoSet.reduce((res, item) => {
  const result = { ...res };
  if (item.language) {
    const language = item.language.languageValue;
    const category = item.categoryValue;
    result[language] = category;
  }
  return result;
  }, { it: undefined, de: undefined, en: undefined );


  export const fn2 = article => article.titleDtoSet.reduce((res, item) => {
  const result = { ...res };
  if (item.language) {
    const language = item.language.languageValue;
    const category = item.titleValue;
    result[language] = title;
  }
  return result;
  }, { it: undefined, de: undefined, en: undefined );
```

Comment: perhaps `const fn = (article, dtoset) => article[dtoset].reduce(...`?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not appropriate for Stack Overflow and should be on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you would need function which you will pass to the reduce function as a callback. For this you can use a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function#:~:text=In%20mathematics%20and%20computer%20science,a%20function%20as%20its%20result.) which is basically a function that returns a function. We can call this function `dry`

```
const dry = (fieldName) => (res, item) => {
  const result = { ...res };
  if (item.language) {
    const language = item.language.languageValue;
    result[language] = item[fieldName];
  }
  return result;
}
```

then we can extract the initial object that is being passed to the reduce callback:

```
const intialValueObject = { it: undefined, de: undefined, en: undefined };
```

and then pass the `dry` function to the reduce function as an argument:

```
export const fn1 = article => article.categoryValueDtoSet.reduce(dry('categoryValue'), { ...initialValueObject });

export const fn2 = article => article.titleDtoSet.reduce(dry('titleValue'), { ...intialValueObject });
```

Comment: Thank you! Got the idea

Answer (score 0):

There is pretty much always a way. Could you be more specific with your constraints?

If nothing else, you can share the reduce logic

```js
let reducer = (res, item) => {
  const result = { ...res };
  if (item.language) {
    const language = item.language.languageValue;
    const category = item.categoryValue;
    result[language] = category;
  }
  return result;
}

export const fn1 = article => article.categoryValueDtoSet.reduce(reducer, { it: undefined, de: undefined, en: undefined });


export const fn2 = article => article.titleDtoSet.reduce(reducer, { it: undefined, de: undefined, en: undefined });
```

Answer (score 0):

Most straightforward and simple, albeit with bad naming because I don't know what all this represents:

```js
function reduceIt(it) {
  return it.reduce((res, item) => {
    const result = { ...res };
    if (item.language) {
      const language = item.language.languageValue;
      const category = item.categoryValue;
      result[language] = category;
    }
    return result;
  }, { it: undefined, de: undefined, en: undefined });
}

export const fn1 = article => reduceIt(article.categoryValueDtoSet);
export const fn2 = article => reduceIt(article.titleDtoSet);
```

Comment: A bit confused, I don't understand wherefrom fn2 is getting title here?